# Errors while passing character parameters to a R UDF in Vertica

Tags: r, vertica

I've asked vertica support for this as well but wondering if any1 here got the same issue.

I'm working with Vertica Analytic Database v6.1.3-0
I'm using R version 3.0.0 - which comes with the Vertica R language pack.

I'm trying to create a simple UDF that uses a parameter passed with the USING PARAMETERS keyword.

This is the R code :

```
testFun <- function(x,y) {
# extract the function parameters from y
  parameter <- y[["parameter"]] # parameter to be passed
  sum(x[,1])
}

testFunParams <- function()
{
params <- data.frame(datatype=rep(NA, 1), length=rep(NA,1),scale=rep(NA,1),name=rep(NA,1))
params[1,1] <- "varchar"
params[1,2] <- "40"
params[1,4] <- "parameter"
params
}

testFunFactory <- function()
{
list(
name=testFun
,udxtype=c("transform")
,intype=c("int")
,outtype=c("varchar(200)")
,outnames=c('test')
,parametertypecallback=testFunParams
,volatility=c("stable")
,strict=c("called_on_null_input")
)
}
```

In Vertica I run the library :

```
drop library r_test cascade;
create or replace library r_test as '.../testFun.r' language 'R';
create transform function testFun as name 'testFunFactory' library r_test;

create table test as select 1 as x union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7;
select testFun(x) over() from test;
> ERROR 3399:  Failure in UDx RPC call InvokeGetParameterType(): Error calling    getParameterType() in User Defined Object [testFun] at   [/scratch_a/release/vbuild/vertica/UDxFence/vertica-udx-R.cpp:245], error code: 0, message:   Error happened in getParameterType : not compatible with REALSXP
```

I've tried Vertica's example for a function with parameters and it worked, when I changed the parameter type to varchar it failed.

What can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tested your configuration and it returned the following error

[...] Error happened in getParameterType : not compatible with REALSXP [...]

And after some tweaking I know what happened. You saved "scale" as a character value instead of a numeric in your "testFunParams".

Test if that helps you =)